# How to type callback parameter which will be received by curried function

Tags: typescript

I've trying to create props getter fabric. It's a curried function. Outer func receives `defaultParams` and `propsConstructor` callback. `propsConstructor` is a logic to calculate new props object based on `defaultParams` and new props which will be received after invoking inner function.

**Propblem**: `props` which will be received on invoking nested function typed incorrectly. For now I can manage cases when I need to type some callbacks and some of it's arguments will be received later after invoking of a nested function

```js
// basic types
type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>
type AnyObject = Record<string, unknown>
type ObjectType = EmptyObject | AnyObject

export type PropsConstructor<
    DefParams extends AnyObject,
    Props extends AnyObject, // will be received later after invoking nested function
    ReturnObject extends AnyObject
> = (defaultParams: DefParams, props: Props) => ReturnObject

/**
 * @description input field props getter fabric
 * @returns props object that will be passed to inpuit
 */
export const createPropsGetter = <
    DefParams extends AnyObject,
    ReturnObject extends AnyObject,
    Constr extends PropsConstructor<DefParams, AnyObject, ReturnObject>
>({
    defaultParams,
    propsConstructor,
}: {
    defaultParams: DefParams
    propsConstructor: Constr
}) => {
    return <NewProps extends AnyObject>(props: NewProps) => {
        return propsConstructor(defaultParams, props)
    }
}

const defaultParams = { one: 1, two: 2 }
type Props = { four: number }
type ReturnObject = typeof defaultParams & Props

const propsConstructor: PropsConstructor<
    typeof defaultParams,
    { four: 4 },
    ReturnObject
> = (defParams, props) => ({ ...defParams, ...props })

// const getter: <{ four: number }>(props: { four: number }) => AnyObject
const getter = createPropsGetter({
    defaultParams,
    propsConstructor,
})

const props = getter({ four: 4 }) 
props // AnyObject
```

**Goal:** define type for the callback parameter. Parameter will be received later after invoking nested function

**Problem**: props received from nested function and resulted object are typed as AnyObject

Answer (score 1):

After some trials find a workaround:

```js
export const createPropsGetter = <
    DefParams extends AnyObject,
    // set second param to any to suppress ts warning
    Constr extends (def: DefParams, properties: any) => AnyObject
>({
    defaultParams,
    propsConstructor,
}: {
    defaultParams: DefParams
    propsConstructor: Constr
}) => {
    return <NewProps extends AnyObject>(props: NewProps) => {
        // infer type of passed callback
        const constr: typeof propsConstructor = propsConstructor

        // hardcode return type with 'as'
        return constr(defaultParams, props) as ReturnType<typeof constr>
    }
}
```

Works if callback will be typed with `PropsConstructor` util type

```js
const defaultParams = { one: 1, two: 2 }
const newParams = { four: 4 }
type ReturnedProps = typeof defaultParams & typeof newParams

const propsConstructor: PropsConstructor<
    typeof defaultParams,
    typeof newParams,
    ReturnedProps
> = (defParams, props) => ({ ...defParams, ...props })

const getter = createPropsGetter({
    defaultParams,
    propsConstructor,
})
const props = getElementProps({ four: 4 }) // typed as ReturnedProps: { one: 1, two: 2, four: 4 }
```